# Where can i find the transferred smart contract to the gnosis safe address?

Tags: gnosis-safe

so ive created a smart contract on manifold.xyz to launch my ERC-721 NFT (0x11BE0997e2EC35a7AF616bd4d973c8A367201B4C)

but then some partners asked me to change the ownership into multisig address which is gnosis-safe. So ive created gnosis contract. Then i transferred the ERC-721 contract ownership through "write as proxy" and send it to the gnosis address (eth:0xB19ffB465f07bD9DB382d53ECfd4529eD5b047Ca). But now i cannot set/do anything with my ERC-721 contract (owner transfer txhash: 0xeb0ea112a97f5ee7bc1df79285c6e479fde52f74e245338a3fdaa528c70bc262)

I would like to ask whether i can transfer the ownership back to my metamask address or access my ERC-721 contract as the gnosis address?

Thank you.
have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

So the gnosis safe wallet has to have a certain number of signers to confirm a transaction. Maybe that is the issue here is everyone signing the transaction? Assuming you have access to send transactions from this gnosis safe wallet.

but the owner of the contract is now the gnosis safe wallet, meaning only that wallet can interact with the onlyOwner functions.

here is a help article for interacting with a contract from a gnosis safe wallet, hope it helps!

https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/3738081-contract-interactions

So following the link I sent you, you would input your contract address, then this would be the ABI:

```
[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
```

Select "transferOwnership" as the method, and enter the new owners address as the parameter.

Comment: Hi! i've tried the  contract interactions but it only shown "implementation" option, is it possible to send the ownership back to my metamask address? :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to help you out